# How can i change a One-To-Many relationsship entry with Hibernate in JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a Class called 'Customer'. This class has a OneToMany relationsship to a nother Class called 'Auftraege'.

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = "all.customers", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c")
public class Customer implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public Customer() {
    super();
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "_id_auftrag", referencedColumnName = "_id")
private Set<Auftraege> auftraege = new HashSet<Auftraege>();

[getter/setter]

 }
```

Auftraege.class

```
@Entity
public class Auftraege implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public Auftraege() {
    super();
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int _id;

@Column(unique = true)
private int auftragsnummer;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date datum;

@Column(length = 60)
private String themengebiet;

@Column(length = 10)
private String status;

@Column(length = 350)
private String begruendung;

public int get_id() {
    return _id;
}

public void set_id(int _id) {
    this._id = _id;
}

public int getAuftragsnummer() {
    return auftragsnummer;
}

public void setAuftragsnummer(int auftragsnummer) {
    this.auftragsnummer = auftragsnummer;
}

public Date getDatum() {
    return datum;
}

public void setDatum(Date datum) {
    this.datum = datum;
}

public String getThemengebiet() {
    return themengebiet;
}

public void setThemengebiet(String themengebiet) {
    this.themengebiet = themengebiet;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getBegruendung() {
    return begruendung;
}

public void setBegruendung(String begruendung) {
    this.begruendung = begruendung;
}

}
```

Now, i want to change the 'status' Attribute in the 'Auftraege' class to another entry.
For that i have a datatable which holds the customer and if i clicked a button (each row has one) than i want to get the clicked row customer and change the 'status' attribute from the 'Auftraege' class. But how can i do that ?  Always i got all the Auftraege as a list from the Customer, but i want just the one, i've clicked.
Here's the class which i called when i click the button in the table:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class AuswertungBean implements Serializable {

    public void genehmigen(Customer c) {
    Customer cu = c;
    for (Auftraege a : cu.getAuftraege()) {

        System.out.println(a.getAuftragsnummer());

    }
}
```

Comment: Well, pass the ID of the clicked Auftraege, use the EntityManager to find the Auftraege with the given ID, and set its status. The fact that Customer has a OneToMany association with Auftraege is irrelevant. Also, please make your life, and the life of your coworkers simpler by respecting the Java naming conventions. Also, the column _id_auftrag should really be named customer_id, since it contains the ID of a consumer.

Comment: isn't the question about the view layer? sorry, but I can't see that hibernate/JPA should be involved here!

Comment: `but i want just the one, i've clicked` as @JBNizet states, send the `Auftraege._id` or Auftraege's natural id when user click on the row, so you can find it in `customer.auftraege`, and do whatever you want with it.

Comment: @JB Nizet - > that was the solution. Thx. And yes next time i will assume your suggestions